# NetworkOnMainThreadException on 3.0 and higher

Tags: android, json

I did learn about this on an article that, on 3.0 and higher, one has to use the `AsyncTask` to preform any network activity. Knowing this, I used the `AsyncTask` to call on a `JSON` request, and my main class looks like this:

**MainPage.java**

```
public class doTheFare extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        progress = new ProgressDialog(MainPage.this);
        progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progress.setMessage("Processing Request ...");
        progress.show();
        UserFunctions users = new UserFunctions();
        jObj = users.distanceGET(location.getText().toString(), destination.getText().toString());
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            jArr = jObj.getJSONArray("rows");
            jObj1 = jArr.getJSONObject(0);
            jArr2 = jObj1.getJSONArray("elements");
            jObj2 = jArr2.getJSONObject(0);
            jObj3 = jObj2.getJSONObject("distance");
            distance_value = jObj3.getString("text");
            String value = jObj3.getString("value");
            SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
            String sF = getPrefs.getString("startFare", "10");
            String pM = getPrefs.getString("perKilo", "27");
            startFare = Double.parseDouble(sF);
            perKilo = Double.parseDouble(pM);
            perMeter=perKilo/5;
            int parseDistance = Integer.parseInt(value);
            double fare = startFare+((parseDistance/200)*perMeter);
            int roundedValue = (int)Math.round(fare);
            //Fare to send
            taxiFare = String.valueOf(roundedValue);
            Log.i("Fare Estimate", taxiFare);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        progress.dismiss();
        from_split = location.getText().toString();
        to_split = destination.getText().toString();
        if(from_split.contains(","))
        {
            from_fill = from_split.split(",");
        }
        else
        {
            from_fill = from_split.split(" ");
        }
        if(to_split.contains(","))
        {
            to_fill = to_split.split(",");
        }
        else
        {
            to_fill = to_split.split(" ");
        }

        send_location=from_fill[0];
        send_destination=to_fill[0];
        send_fare = taxiFare;
        send_distance = distance_value;
        if(isMode.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        {
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hours = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            if(hours<6)
                isMode = "nMode";
            else if(hours>=21)
                isMode = "nMode";
            else
                isMode = "dMode";
        }
        Intent toResults = new Intent(MainPage.this, ResultsDisplay.class);
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putString("TO", send_location);
        extras.putString("FROM", send_destination);
        extras.putString("FARE", send_fare);
        extras.putString("DISTANCE", send_distance);
        extras.putString("GMAPFROM", from_split.toString());
        extras.putString("GMAPTO", to_split.toString());
        extras.putString("MODE",isMode);
        toResults.putExtras(extras);
        startActivity(toResults);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

In this `Activity` I have a `OnClickListener` that calls this `AsyncTask` even so the program is giving me the following

```
05-10 03:02:19.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1815): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-10 03:02:19.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1815): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
05-10 03:02:19.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1815):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
05-10 03:02:19.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1815):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
05-10 03:02:19.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1815):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
05-10 03:02:19.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1815):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
05-10 03:02:19.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1815):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
05-10 03:02:19.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1815):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
05-10 03:02:19.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1815):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
05-10 03:02:19.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1815):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
05-10 03:02:19.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1815):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
05-10 03:02:19.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1815):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
05-10 03:02:19.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1815):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
05-10 03:02:19.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1815):     at com.example.calculator_taxi_fare.functions.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:56)
05-10 03:02:19.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1815):     at com.example.calculator_taxi_fare.functions.UserFunctions.distanceGET(UserFunctions.java:28)
05-10 03:02:19.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1815):     at com.example.calculator_taxi_fare.MainPage$doTheFare.onPreExecute(MainPage.java:251)
05-10 03:02:19.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1815):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
05-10 03:02:19.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1815):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
05-10 03:02:19.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1815):     at com.example.calculator_taxi_fare.MainPage$6.onClick(MainPage.java:230)
05-10 03:02:19.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1815):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
05-10 03:02:19.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1815):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
05-10 03:02:19.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1815):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
05-10 03:02:19.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1815):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-10 03:02:19.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1815):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-10 03:02:19.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1815):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
05-10 03:02:19.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1815):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-10 03:02:19.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1815):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-10 03:02:19.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1815):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-10 03:02:19.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1815):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-10 03:02:19.823: E/AndroidRuntime(1815):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    location.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
```

Am I implementing this the right way ?? Please Help!

I also have implemented the Google `PlacesAutocomplete` in this app, in which the results/suggestions do show but are not select able on `3.0 or higher` a `Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0` error shows up. The code is as follows:

location.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        autoLocation = (Places) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
        location.setText(autoLocation.description);
        location.clearFocus();
        destination.requestFocus();
        Log.d("AutoCompleteTask", location.getText().toString());
            }
});
destination.setAdapter(new PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item));
destination.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
{

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        autoDestination = (Places) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
        destination.setText(autoDestination.description);
        destination.clearFocus();
        calculate.requestFocus();
        Log.d("AutoCompleteTask2", destination.getText().toString());
            }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems this code are getting data from network.
You have put it in workthread, put it on the doinBackground();

```
        jObj = users.distanceGET(location.getText().toString(), destination.getText().toString());
```

Comment: I have added the AutoCompleteEditText component

Answer (score 1):

It seems your `distanceGET` method is doing network operation

According to doc [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

> onPreExecute(), invoked on the UI thread before the task is executed.
>   This step is normally used to setup the task, for instance by showing
>   a progress bar in the user interface.

Do your network things in `doInBackground`

Answer (score 1):

You must Set your network operation on doInBackground() Method

```
jObj = users.distanceGET(location.getText().toString(), destination.getText().toString())
```

Must write in doInBackground()

Answer (score 1):

Dont do network operations in pre-execute. Do network operations in doInBackground, that is the correct way.

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
UserFunctions users = new UserFunctions();
    jObj = users.distanceGET(location.getText().toString(),
           destination.getText().toString());
    try{
        jArr = jObj.getJSONArray("rows");
        jObj1 = jArr.getJSONObject(0);
        --------------------
        --------------------
        }catch(Exception e){
        }
}
```